# Problem in understanding the use of object in PHP

Tags: php, object, parsing, arguments

```
<?php

class A
{
    public $x=40;
    function sum($x)
    {
        return $this->x + $this->x;
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
            echo "The class ".__class__." has been created<br>";
    }
    function sub($integers)
    {
        echo 2*$integers."<br>";
    }
}
$obj= new A;
//Will the 40 in paranthesis will be passed as argument to the function  sum($x) above?

echo $obj->sum(40);   //It throws an error if I don't pass anything in sum but it will not take 50 it is taking 40
$obj->sub(50);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `sum` requires a parameter `$x`, but doesn't use it. Instead is uses *property* `$this->x` of the class, which is initialized with a value of 40.

Since both functions (methods) have non-optional parameters, you have to specify the parameters when calling them.

I think it may be beneficial to study the documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php (and, more generally, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php )